# I'm trying to install MySQL 5.5 onto a CentOS 6.7 server

Tags: mysql, installation, mariadb

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.5 onto a CentOS 6.7 server but I keep getting an error message similar to the one below for about 25 different conflicts all for mariadb-galera or mariadb-galera-server:

```
file /usr/bin/mysql from install of mariadb-galera-5.5.39-18.el6.art.x86_64
conflicts with file from package MySQL55-client-5.5.46-1.cp1148.x86_64
```

Any ideas on how I can overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have MariaDB installed. First of all remove MariaDB:

```
yum remove mariadb*
```

Check the MariaDB repo in `/etc/yum.repos.d`. It should be called `MariaDB.repo` or something like that. If the file exists either remove it or edit it and disable the repo (set enabled=0).

I guess (based on your errors) that you already have a repository that contains MySQL 5.5. If not, install Remi repo. See a link here: https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/145f3d4c0dafcfb7246b

Finally, you shoul be able to install MySQL 5.5.